# mypy possible cyclic definition: TypedDict Class Attribute is Parent Class Reference

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm working with MyPy as my type checker, and I ran into this strange behavior. I was hoping someone could point me to a reference that explains why this happens (A work around would be nice too).

The following code raises 0 errors with MyPy:

```py
class HackerNewsComment:
    # ...
    kids: List["HackerNewsComment"] # A list of child comments under this one
```

For reference, this also raises 0 errors.

```py
class HackerNewsComment(object): # Even putting `Generic[T]` is ok according to mypy.
    # ...
    kids: List["HackerNewsComment"] # A list of child comments under this one
```

But suddenly:

```py
class HackerNewsComment(TypedDict):
    # ...
    kids: List["HackerNewsComment"] # A list of child comments under this one
```

Mypy then says: `Cannot resolve name "HackerNewsComment" (possible cyclic definition)`.

**What in the `TypedDict` class is causing mypy to panic?**

Possible relevant information:

- mypy version: 0.910
- python version: 3.8.5
- OS: WSL on Windows

Comment: See https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/731#issuecomment-752157487, it's because `HackerNewsComment` as a `TypedDict` is erased to a `dict` at runtime. `print(type(HackerNewsComment(kids=[]))` will print `<class 'dict'>`. To use `HackerNewsComment` recursively, you could make it a `@dataclass`. and then do `HackerNewsComment(**api_response)` where `api_response` is the returned `dict` from Hacker News API.

Comment: Thanks for this, if you want to write this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this GitHub issue "Support recursive types"](http://github.com/python/mypy/issues/731#issuecomment-752157487), it's because `HackerNewsComment` as a `TypedDict` is erased to a `dict` at runtime. `print(type(HackerNewsComment(kids=[]))` will print `<class 'dict'>`. To use `HackerNewsComment` recursively, you could make it a `@dataclass`. and then do `HackerNewsComment(**api_response)` where `api_response` is the returned `dict` from the Hacker News API.